# docker ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2

Tags: linux, windows, docker

I am using windows 10 OS. I want to build an container based on linux so I can replicate code and dependencies developed from ubuntu. When I try to build it outputs Error message as above.

From my understanding docker for desktop runs linux OS kernel under-the-hood therefore allowing window users to run linux based containers, not sure why it is outputting this error.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

RUN apt update \
    && apt install -y htop python3-dev wget


RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
    && mkdir root/.conda \
    && sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
    && rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
    
RUN conda create -y -n ml python=3.7

COPY . src/
RUN /bin/bash -c "cd src \
    && source activate ml \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

requirements.txt contains:

```
apturl==0.5.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
bleach==2.1.2
Brlapi==0.6.6
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
command-not-found==0.3
configparser==5.0.1
cryptography==2.1.4
cupshelpers==1.0
dataclasses==0.7
```

When I run docker build command it outputs:
`1.649 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apturl==0.5.2 1.649 ERROR: No matching distribution found for apturl==0.5.2` Deleting it and running it lead to another error. All error seem to be associated with ubuntu packages.

Am I not running a ubuntu container? why aren't I allowed to install ubuntu packages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to install ubuntu packages with `pip` (which is for python packages")

try `apt install -y  apturl`
If you want to install python packages write `pip install package_name`

Comment: Thanks Elvin. So I must separate ubuntu packages and run `apt install -y requirements_ubuntu.txt`? Since I have a lot of packages, I don't want to write apt install for all of them.

Comment: I am not sure how to install ubuntu packages from txt file. Search you will find it.

And if you like accept my solution.Thanks

Comment: Wait, what I am trying to do is download python then download all requirements. If I create ubuntu container then download python then install requirements.txt with "apturl" inside, wouldn't that work?